# Is there a head and tail method for Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I loaded a csv file into 'dataset' and tried to execute dataset.head(), but it reports an error. How to check the head or tail of a numpy array? without specifying specific lines?

Comment: You can check it via `array[:head]` and `array[tail:]`. You have to specify head and tail since numpy doesn't have any default for that (unlike pandas where you *can* specify the number of lines as well).

Comment: This is nice too.

Answer (score 96):

For a head-like function you can just slice the array using `dataset[:10]`.

For a tail-like function you can just slice the array using `dataset[-10:]`.

Comment: Warning: dataset[-1:] returns the last element of the array, but dataset[-0:] returns the entire array, so tail(0) returns everything rather than nothing. See my answer below which fixes this.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this for any python iterable.

PEP-3132 which is in python 3.x (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) can use the `*` symbol for the 'rest' of the iterable.

To do what you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array((1,2,3))
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> head, *tail = np.array((1,2,3))
>>> head
1
>>> tail
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works well:

```
def nparray_tail(x: np.array, n:int):
    """
    Returns tail N elements of array.
    :param x: Numpy array.
    :param n: N elements to return on end.
    :return: Last N elements of array.
    """
    if n == 0:
        return x[0:0]  # Corner case: x[-0:] will return the entire array but tail(0) should return an empty array.
    else:
        return x[-n:]  # Normal case: last N elements of array.
```

### Discussion

As a bonus, this fixes a non-intuitive corner case in the answer from @feedMe: `dataset[-0:]` returns the entire array, not an empty array as one would expect when requesting the last 0 elements on the tail end of the array. This is consistent with the `.tail()` function in Pandas.